# What does "o" mean as a variable prefix?

Tags: c#, naming

in oCn? What is the rule?

```
using(SqlConnection oCn = new SqlConnection(
        "Server=(local);Database=Pubs;User ID=TestUser1;Password=foo1;")) {
        oCn.Open();
        ...
    }
```

I found that type of naming in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163799.aspx

Comment: maybe is someone convention..

Comment: It means whatever the original author intended it to mean. You are free to name your variables just about anyway you want.

Comment: Maybe "Open" Connection?

Comment: It probably means "object". Back in the days of VB, objects and classes were a big deal, so people prefixed their objects with "o" and their classes with "cls".

Comment: @Matt: Nah.  Every question of the form, "What does X mean in C#?" has a single answer: "Whatever Jon Skeet wants it to."

Answer (score 50, accepted):

An entirely obsolete way of saying that "Cn" is an **o**bject.

Comment: This really sums it up nicely :)

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that it is not obsolete for systems (such as scripting languages) that do not enforce types.  Encoding the desired type in a variables name can aid in comprehension of what is meant to be going on in a program.

Comment: @PeterM: It can aid comprehension.. Right up until you decide to change the type to something else at which point it's completely meaningless.

Answer (score 16):

I am afraid that it is a remainder of some [hungarian dialect notation](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/C_Sharp/Hungarian_Notation.htm) for an object.

In C# and .NET I consider this useless.

**EDIT** By the way I consider Hungarian notation containing type and/ore scope information useless in C#. [I do like Apps Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation#Systems_vs._Apps_Hungarian)

Comment: The only "notation" I ever liked with was `I` for interface. I'm glad it stuck around in C#.

Comment: I always liked the 'java' addition of -able at the end. It doesn't get any better than `ISerializable`.

Comment: I don't like -able because it beaks the impeccable grammar of "I serialize." by leaving out the "am" in "I am serializable." Imagine if Apple had called it the iPhonable.

Comment: @Dan - There is a big difference between being serializable or being able to serialize.

Comment: That's one interpretation. I was thinking more like ice cream inheriting "IMelt", meaning the object itself could melt, as opposed to a blowtorch inheriting "IMelt" meaning that it melts other things. Since this is an interface, rather than a base class, it should be clear that we are not inheriting actions (the ability to melt [serialize] other objects) but rather methods of interaction (the ability to be melted [serialized] by something). There are also some names that just don't work well with -able. For example, "IEnable" vs. "IEnableable".

Comment: Also consider -ible words: "IEat" would logically become "IEdible" not "IEatable". While "IEdible" works, you're still forced to give up '-able' so why bother have it to begin with?

Answer (score 13):

In this case, "o" means object.  It's an attempt at using the "systems" variation of hungarian notation.

There are two types of hungarian: [Systems and Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).  Systems uses a prefix to identify the type of data stored.  For example, the "i" in iCounter would indicate that the variable was an integer.

Apps hungarian took a completely different approach and specifies that the prefix should indicate the purpose of the data.  For example, the "rw" in rwPosition would mean row.

The windows api used Systems hungarian.  This led to a large number of other programmers also using it.  The unfortunate aspect is that when changes were made to the api, they kept the old variable names even when the actual data type changed.  This led to large amounts of confusion as to what data type a parameter to a given API function should be passed.  Especially around various handles.

In the .Net coding guidelines, [MS explicitly states that hungarian shouldn't be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).  The reality is that they are talking about "Systems" hungarian; which I 100% agree with.  "Apps" hungarian on the other hand has a ton of uses as you are describing the data, not the type.

At the end of the day just remove the "o".  It adds nothing to the program.

Oh, and for interesting reading, check out Joel's take on this at: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html

Answer (score 5):

It probably means `object` like in some complex type that does not fit well with the same (ridiculous) convention that names strings `strMyString` and ints `iMyInt` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This "rule" comes directly from [How To Write Unmaintainable Code](http://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html):

> **o_apple obj_apple**
>
> Use an "o" or "obj" prefix for each instance of the class to show that you're thinking of the big, polymorphic picture.

Answer (score 1):

o is for object,

it's a, not very usefull, convention where by the type of the variable was incuded in the name, so a string was strWhatever. sometimes i even saw obj, i.e. objCn

Answer (score 1):

As @Humberto suggested, appears to be the developer using [Hungarian Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).

Answer (score 1):

When I started working as a programmer 10 years ago, the compagny I worked for was using a similar naming convention.  I can't remember what is the convention name but I do remember that all the object instances had the "o" prefix, standing for Object.