# JavaScript Constructor Function Instantiated Object Prefix Convention

Tags: javascript, instance, naming, prefix, convention

In JavaScript, is there a naming convention for objects instantiated from constructor functions?

For example, if I had a constructor function set up like so:

```
function Dance(style, timing) {
    this.style = style; // for reflection
    this.timing = timing;
}

var waltz = new Dance('waltz' , '3/4');
var rumba = new Dance('rumba' , '4/4');
```

So a console command would look like this:

> console> waltz.timing
>  3/4
>
> console> rumba.timing
>   4/4

What I'm looking for is a convention saying that waltz and rumba are instantiated objects;  like prefixing with an "o"?

```
var oWaltz = new Dance('waltz' , '3/4');
var oRumba = new Dance('rumba' , '4/4');
```

I actually (*gasp!*) Googled and did a little homework before asking this question, and came up with the following:

a. Crockford's "JavaScript: The Good Parts." Most notably, he recommends using a capital letter on the actual constructor function:

> There is a convention that all constructor functions are named with an initial capital (Pg. 49).

Fine, but I don't see any convention regarding *instances* of these constructor functions. All his examples are prefixed with "my," like so..

```
var myTango = new Dance('tango' , '4/4');
```

> console> myTango.timing
>   4/4

...which is great for an example, but is not a reasonable convention.

b. I also dug up this thread, which calls the "o" prefix "Hungarian dialect," and also calls it obsolete:
[What does "o" mean as a variable prefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096453/what-does-o-mean-as-a-variable-prefix)

c. We also have the convention of prefixing variables that contain jQuery wrapped set with a "$" like the following, which would select all <button> tags on the page, create a jQuery wrapped set, and assign it to the $buttons variable:

```
$buttons = $('button');
```

d. Finally, a simple Google search for "JavaScript object instance prefix" yields the underscore "_" convention for private functions; in this example if we were to add a private prototype function, it might look like this:

```
Dance.prototype._lessonCost = function(minutes) { return ($1.50 * minutes); }
```

Which, again, is not really of any help, which brings me here.

If you made it this far, thank for answering :^) I feel like I'm missing something; like there's a fundamental flaw with my technique.

Comment: What would be the point of such a prefix? Most values in JavaScript are objects (or pretend to be objects, like strings or numbers).

Comment: To facilitate easy identification of explicitly instantiated objects. For example, imagine an instance named "delineatedArgVal." What is that? In contrast, take "oDelineatedArgVal." I can immediately see that this is an instance of a contructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if its a standard but usually instances of objects start with a lowercase letter and then camel case the rest.  I'm not aware of any prefixes and think this would just cause a bunch of extra code to pass to the client.

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
```

Comment: Yes this is (a) above, and what Crockford did in the examples in his book. It works well for snippet examples, but seems a bit academic for a production environment.

Comment: I think what your missing is that the instances start with a lower case letter.  Using this convention you know every time you see a lowercase letter that is an instance.  If you look at heavy OO code in Java you see this all the time.  The constructor used to initialize an instance that has the same name as the constructor just lower cased/camel cased.